# KryzhanovskyCssMinifier doesn't work with MsieJsEngine but does with V8JsEngine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundletransformer, kryzhanovskycssminifier, csso

I am using the latest BundleTransformer for ASP.NET.

I have an extremely simple bundle file with one LESS file:

```
 var cssBundle = new CustomStyleBundle("~/Content/css/bundle").Include(                                              
                                       "~/Content/css/test.less");
 bundles.Add(cssBundle);
```

The LESS file I've made as simple as possible to prove it is actually correctly interpreting as LESS.

```
.something
{
    ol, ul
    {
        list-style: none;
    }
}
```

When I try to use V8JsEngine it works as expected (relevant web.config shown):

```
<css defaultMinifier="KryzhanovskyCssMinifier" usePreMinifiedFiles="false">
    <minifiers>
         <add name="KryzhanovskyCssMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Csso.Minifiers.KryzhanovskyCssMinifier, BundleTransformer.Csso" />
    </minifiers>
</css>

<csso>
  <css disableRestructuring="false" />
  <jsEngine name="V8JsEngine" />
</csso>
```

This gives me the correct CSS:

```
.something ol,.something ul{list-style:none}
```

However when I switch to MsieJSEngine

```
<csso>
  <css disableRestructuring="false" />
  <jsEngine name="MsieJsEngine" />
</csso>
```

I get the following bizarrely incorrect CSS - with UL completely stripped out.

```
.something ol{list-style:none}
```

I just can't quite fathom how this is even possible. It has been interpreted correctly as LESS, but completely stripped out the UL from the list. Incidentally if I make it just a pure css file without the `.something` class I get the same incorrect result.

Fortunately it seems to work fine with V8JsEngine so I can keep on, but I'm posting this here hopefully to help others and because I'm very curious if there's something I did wrong.

---

File versions:

```
BundleTransformer.Core - 1.9.3.0
BundleTransformer.Csso - 1.9.1.0
BundleTransformer.Less - 1.9.1.0
BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax - 1.9.1.0
```

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Only switching to the V8 engine

Comment: I did the same and it works, which is quite annoying. I had to install VC++ 2012 Redistributable Package on the IIS because it is required by V8JsEngine. I find that CSS+JS packaging is the biggest pain in the ass when it comes to entire MVC, they always break with updates.

Answer (score 1):

For BundleTransformer.Csso need the full support of ECMAScript 5, that is implemented only in `ChakraJsRt` mode of the [MSIE JavaScript Engine for .NET](http://github.com/Taritsyn/MsieJavaScriptEngine). Quote from the documentation:

> JsRT version of Chakra JavaScript engine (supports ECMAScript 5). Requires Internet Explorer 11 or higher on the machine.

Incidentally, in description of the [BundleTransformer.Csso NuGet-package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Csso/) has the following requirement:

> For correct working of this module is recommended to install the following NuGet packages: JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8 or JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie (only in the `ChakraJsRt` mode).

Comment: Starting with version [1.5.4](https://github.com/Taritsyn/MsieJavaScriptEngine/releases/tag/v1.5.4) in `ChakraActiveScript` mode added native support of ECMAScript 5 (without polyfills).
In version [1.6.0](https://github.com/Taritsyn/MsieJavaScriptEngine/releases/tag/v1.6.0) `ChakraJsRt` was divided into 2 modes: `ChakraIeJsRt` and `ChakraEdgeJsRt`.